# How can I use AWS Lex to ask multiple yes/no questions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am trying to create a custom slot type to hold the user response for yes / no values but it looks like Lex does not recognize `Yes`, `No` or `Sure` as input on my custom slot type. Are there limits with slot types on what values should we use?

I was hoping to use Lex as a way to solve basic helpdesk problems before forwarding a user on to a human. My questions are things like "Have you turned it off an on?", which I'm expecting a "yes/no" response.

It seems like Lex is unable to understand these answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a hacky solution.

Within your Lambda function, continuously respond with `ConfirmIntent` and check `intentRequest.currentIntent.confirmationStatus` for `Confirmed` and `Denied`. State can be managed through a `slot` parameter or `outputSessionAttribute` (e.g. incrementing an integer).

This feels like it's breaking the intended flow process of Lex, but it gets the job done.

**Please post an answer if you think there is a better way**

Comment: i am using ConfirmIntent for similar use case, but it is confirming the status even if i type "no". i am not making any extra slot for this. am i missing something?

Comment: what is the point in asking similar question. i have similar issue, i had similar solution, just asked your opinion.

Comment: @sid8491 You must be missing something. I can't tell from the information provided. Please provide more information. Preferably with your own question.

Answer (score -1):

You should be able to use the built-in `AMAZON.YesIntent` and `AMAZON.NoIntent` for these.

Comment: Unfortunately, from the AWS Lex documentation: `Amazon Lex doesn't support AMAZON.YesIntent and AMAZON.NoIntent.`

Comment: these are for Alexa